# Django foreignkey relationships in templates

Tags: python, django, templates, view, relationships

I've seen some examples of how to do this on SO but none of them have guided me towards the glory I so desire.

Here are the fields I'm working with:

models.py

```
class ServerFunctions(models.Model):
    server_function = models.CharField(max_length=12)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Server Function"

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.server_function

class Inventory(models.Model):
    server_function = models.ForeignKey(ServerFunctions, null=False, blank=False)
```

views.py

```
def show_details(request, host_id=1):
    host_info = Inventory.objects.filter(id=host_id).values()
    return render_to_response('templates/details.html', {'host_info': host_info})
```

templates/details.html

This gives me the column value from the Inventory table (3) like it should

```
{{ info.server_function_id }}
```

This gives me no output at all.

```
{% for func in info.serverfunctions_set.all %}
    {{ func.server_function }}
{% endfor %}
```

I'm stuck, nothing I've tried seems to work. Thanks for reading.

Comment: You should get rid of that `values()` call at the end of your filter, for a start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `info.serverfunction_set.all` in your template which would be correct if you were traversing a reverse relationship (i.e. you had a `ServerFunction` and wanted all the related `Inventory` items). But you aren't, you have a simple forward relationship between `Inventory` and a `ServerFunction`:

```
{% for info in host_info %}
    {{ func.server_function.server_function }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: `info.server_function.all` does not make any sense. Correct me if i am wrong !

Comment: No it doesn't, you're right. I thought `info` was an object as opposed to a `QuerySet/List`. Updated

Comment: Thanks for replying. I also tried your solution in my template and it produced no output either.

Comment: You don't need `values()` in your query and are you sure there is an `Inventory` object with a `pk` of 1?

Comment: I have removed the .values() from my view. The query still seems to work so that's good. Simply outputting info.server_function_id yields a "3" which is the id for the value "Testing" in the ServerFunctions column. Now, why django is outputing server_function_id instead of the table value server_function is something I also do not understand.

Comment: Something I just noticed. When I do a Inventory.objects.all() in my view and return that to a template and output the server_function field, it looks up fine. The value 3 stored in the Inventory table returns "Testing" on the template like I expect. Only when I do Inventory.objects.filter on the id of the host in the inventory table does it not function.

Comment: Like I mentioned above, that means your query isn't working and you don't have a `Inventory` object with a pk of 1.

Comment: If that was the case, why would the rest of the fields return proper results? All fields in the template show their proper results, it's only the foreignkeys that are only returning the value in their table and not the name from the related table.

Comment: Ah, I made a mistake in my answer. You don't need to iterate over anything except your `QuerySet` (like in @Karthikr answer)

Comment: Well I kind of solved my own problem, but I don't understand why it was a problem. I was outputting {{ info.server_function_id }} I removed the _id and it magically worked. I'm not sure why django does that by default. That's just my inexperience with the software. No additional loops required. I appreciate all of you kind folks working with me on this.

Comment: `server_function_id` is simply the column in your `Inventory` model that tracks the primary key for the respective row in the `ServerFunction`. It's simply an integer value. Whey you removed the `_id` you noticed that the actual object (`ServerFunction`) was returned. That's because Django has bridged the `ForeignKey` for you and turned that integer value into an actual python object

Comment: I wasn't giving Django enough credit. It's much smarter than I expected. I may buy it flowers on Valentines Day.